# what can the county do if my shed violate zoning distance?

Tags: code-compliance, shed, permitting

So, here is the issue. Me being stupid, decided to start building a 12 x 16 shed. (sits on wood foundation)

THEN I started researching what the county permits. The shed has a setback of either 5 or 10 feet (dont know my zone) if its bigger than 120 sqft, which it is. (from what I read - can be wrong i will be calling on friday)

I placed it 3 feet instead. I invested over $4,000 in it with electrical, which passed inspection from a electrical company.

the state is colorado and county is el paso in colorado springs.

YAY ME! so, what can a county do? Can they force me to take it down? if I dont?

Comment: sheds can be moved with out having to dismantle them. What is it sitting on?  WE can not tell you what the county can or can not do as we do not know their laws and codes.

Comment: You should revise your question as it's off-topic. Instead, ask about how to move the shed and provide more information. Or delete the question and ask the county for a variance.

Comment: Contact the zoning board and ask for a variance

Comment: Your shed 12 x 16 is 12 times 16 = 192 Square feet. Your shed the county can force you to move it, or tear it down - it is considered a fire hazard - that is the reason for the 10 foot distance. There are particulars as to why a 10 x 12 could stay and not anything bigger - that is another topic called how to get away with adding a building close to a house and calling it a shed. ALWAYS ALWAYS check building codes before starting any project.

Comment: Many zoning ordinances include "daily fines" for violations, once you are notified, so it could cost you for every day you allow the "nuisance" to continue.

Answer (score 2):

Usually the penalties are right there in the code. My town, it's a fine of  $50/day from the time it was built until the time it's corrected; *i.e.* not a trivial amount. It will vary with the Local Area Having Jursidiction (LAHJ) so only someone from your immediate area would know what might apply to you.

As with most laws, ignorance is not considered a valid excuse, and generally will not sway the zoning board (which is usually what holds sway over this sort of thing, in my area, anyway.)

Comment: +1 And in some jurisdictions, the solution is to make you tear it down (one way to come into compliance).

Comment: It's also possible to "adjust" the property line (with cooperation of abutters) to provide the necessary setback of a building that is difficult to move...